# How to fix 'for' loops didn't stop

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making an array of `int` called `score` but the `for` loops is not working properly (i think the loops didn't stop).

I've tried to remove the `cin >> score[i]` and it turned to normal.

```
array<int, 9> score;

cout << "Score graphics from 1 to ten\n\n";

for(int i = 0; i <= score.size(); i++){
    cout << "The number of people who get " << i + 1 << " : ";
    cin >> score[i];
}
```

I expect the output `The number of people who get 1 : (input)` to `The number of people who get 10 : (input)`

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior as you are dereferencing `array` on past the end. `i <= score.size()` should be `i < score.size()`. That said your problem is very vague. What do you mean "the loops didn't stop"? How often do you see "The number of people who...."?

Comment: The size of `score` is 9 and thus for-loop should be `for(int i = 0; i < score.size(); i++)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= score.size(); i++){
```

Should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < score.size(); i++){
```

Since `score.size()` will return `9`, but the last index of the array is `8`.

With your original code the last run of the loop will just invoke some undefined behavior when accessing an array with an too large index:

```
cin >> score[9];  // score array only goes from 0 to 8!!
```